# Align multiple photos so contents are at same place

Tags: alignment, photoshop

I have multiple images like these[image]

[image]

and a main photo one with which all others need to agree.

I want in all photos the little squares of the top row to be exactly on the same place(cause I use a Photoshop script to sample the color of each square's center using static coordinates). In many photos the camera moved a little so I need to adjust them (mostly vertically) to fix that. Do you know of any way that this can be done easily on many (cause I have like 1000 of them) photos?
I tried open like 30-40 in Photoshop at a time but need a way to place and keep some reference points. You know any way that this can be done? Maybe guides common for all opened files or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align vertical centres and then distribute the horizontal centres with code:

```
function align_tiny_photos()
{ // align and distribute
var idAlgn = charIDToTypeID( "Algn" );
var desc48 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
var ref16 = new ActionReference();
var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
ref16.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
desc48.putReference( idnull, ref16 );
var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
var idADSt = charIDToTypeID( "ADSt" );
var idAdCV = charIDToTypeID( "AdCV" );
desc48.putEnumerated( idUsng, idADSt, idAdCV );
executeAction( idAlgn, desc48, DialogModes.NO );

var idDstr = charIDToTypeID( "Dstr" );
var desc62 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
var ref23 = new ActionReference();
var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
ref23.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
desc62.putReference( idnull, ref23 );
var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
var idADSt = charIDToTypeID( "ADSt" );
var idAdCH = charIDToTypeID( "AdCH" );
desc62.putEnumerated( idUsng, idADSt, idAdCH );
executeAction( idDstr, desc62, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

To use:

```
align_tiny_photos();
```

Comment: Apologies for limited knowledge of actionscript (btw got Photoshop CC 2019) but whats the conditions for using it? Will add it to a script I make and then execute it while having my multiple files opened (assuming I have my main file opened 1st)?

Also tried opening all files as layers in original image with (Scripts->Load files into Stack) but then is there a quick way to save each layer into a seperate file again (layers keep their filename so guess it can be done...maybe with a script)?

Comment: The above script is just basically a macro - kicked out using the ScriptListner plugin. And then tidied up into a function. It will kick out an error if less than two layers are selected. It may be a case that you could modify your initial script and than add the code above. Or keep them separate and run them one after the other. You have the images in front of you, not me and I'm not sure of your whole image process. Yes, you can save out each layer as an image if needed.